# How to integrate openFin with angular 6?

Tags: angular6, openfin

Somebody knows how to integrate angular 6 application with openfin?
I have installed  @types/openfin in my angular application and able to use fin variable. I want to know how to debug the openfin things in browser and how to communicate among various windows. There is no documentation found on internet.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `fin` object will not be available in the global space in your browser - only when launching on OpenFin.

To see your project on OpenFin:

1. Start your project locally
2. Target the project root with the [OpenFin CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openfin-cli)

EDIT - I understand now the user was asking about making the types available when developing.

Here is the latest/greatest way to get `fin` in your global Typescript - https://github.com/built-on-openfin/workspace-starter/blob/main/how-to/common/types/fin.d.ts

Note there is a dependency to install and this file is referenced in the tsconfig of the project I have linked.

Thank you.